# Trying to connect through the web socket and it always get the HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed error

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ssl, https

I'm trying to make an HTTPS proxy server, but I cant make a connection to any server.

Edit: this is the part of the code that, after a client connect to my server, I get the message and try to send to the web. This is the message of a FireFox client trying to connect to Google:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
sock = socket.create_connection((google.com, 443))
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)

fullData=b''

ssl_sock.send(b'CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0\r\nProxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nHost: www.google.com:443\r\n\r\n')

while 1:
    # receive data from web server
    data = ssl_sock.recv(4026)
    print(data)
    if (len(data) > 0):
        fullData+=data
    else:
        break

clientSock.send(fullData)
```

Google should got me a ok message but its getting me an error

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1592
Date: Fri, 24 May 2019 05:28:17 GMT
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>405.</b> <ins>That\xe2\x80\x99s an error.</ins>
  <p>The request method <code>CONNECT</code> is inappropriate for the URL <code>/</code>.  <ins>That\xe2\x80\x99s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: *"i'm trying to make a HTTPS proxy server ..."* - Your code does not create a proxy server. It implements instead a client which tries to use google.com as a proxy. Of course Google does not like to be used as a proxy and therefore refuses the CONNECT method.

Comment: I just copied the part of the code that send to Google because i thought the is other part that got from the client unnecessary

Comment: The problem you describe (implement a proxy) has still nothing to do with the code you show (attempt to access a public server as proxy). And like I said - this is actually the expected answer if you attempt to use google as proxy. I have the feeling that you don't really understand what you are doing but unfortunately fail to represent your problem in a way that others can actually understand it and help you. It might be useful to describe your goal and the approach you have taken in more detail so that one can understand where you make the wrong assumptions and can help you to correct these.

Comment: https://github.com/leosan902/Proxy-HTTP-Python/blob/master/Proxy/HTTPSproxy.py  This is the whole code,i'm creating a server socket and setting the firefox to connect as a proxy for https on the server port and i'm getting the message that firefox sends to my server,in that code above i'm creating a client socket and trying to connect to google and send the message that the browser send to my server

Comment: Your code itself works as a proxy for Firefox. A proxy accepts proxy requests and then issues non-proxy requests to the actually requested server. But your code does not issue a non-proxy request - it issues a proxy request instead. Since this is not expected by the server it gets rejected.

Comment: Example: Firefox issues a HTTP proxy request for example.org. Then your code has to connect to example.org and issue a non-proxy request to this host based on the original proxy request and forward request body to example.org and the response back to Firefox. If Firefox sends a CONNECT request (used for HTTPS) your proxy just has to TCP connect to the target given in CONNECT, ack the request to Firefox within a 200 response  and then simply forward all traffic between Firefox and the target server in both directions.

Comment: Oh thanks this method worked for normal http sites,so i guess i will have to search of how to change the request for a non proxy-request.